# what`s wrong with this code in update statement?

Tags: mysql

```
private function updatedata(){ 
foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
$updates[]="`" . $key . "` = $value";    
 }
 $datavalue=implode("," , $updates);
$query=("UPDATE `users` SET $datavalue WHERE `password`='123' ");
  $sql=  mysql_query($query);
  if(!$sql)throw new Exception('Error:in update statement');else return TRUE;}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention the column you want to put the new data. `UPDATE users SET SOME_COLUMN = '$datavalue' WHERE password='123'`

Comment: I'm guessing some of those `$value` values are strings? They need single quotes. You went to the trouble of quoting `$key` with backticks, but didn't quote `$value`.

Comment: just read mysql_error() output mate

Comment: @juergend Look at  the `$updates`-Array. There is the column. Maybe `$value` have to be like this: `'$value'`.

Comment: Why do you use concatenation for `$key`, but substitution for `$value`? Be consistent, use one or the other.

Comment: Further, we have to assume all the values in `$this->data` have already been correctly escaped against SQL injection. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and consider switching to an API supporting prepared statements, like PDO or MySQLi. The `mysql_*()` functions are now deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the `$value` variable inside `'`. If the string contains spaces it will throw an error. I also deleted the `()` brace at `$query =`.

```
private function updatedata()
{
    foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
        $updates[] = "`" . $key . "` = '$value'";
    }
    $datavalue = implode(",", $updates);
    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET $datavalue WHERE `password` ='123'";
    $sql = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$sql)
        throw new Exception('Error:in update statement');
    else
        return TRUE;
}
```

Also be carful with mysql_query, its depricated! Please use mysqli.

Comment: Please always provide notes and comments on what you specifically changed and why it matters. "Try this" with a block of similar code isn't always helpful to the OP or to future readers.

Comment: thsnks all alot for  your comment  and answer thats solve the error